# Crystal report if then statement

Tags: crystal-reports

I am trying to write the following statement in Crystal but it keeps saying there is an error, can anyone help please.

> ```
> If ("CLA_UNIFORM_PAYMENT_ADVICE_REP"."SUPPLIER_TYPE") = "SUB" Then "CLA_UNIFORM_PAYMENT_ADVICE_REP"."INVOICE_NO"
> Else
> nvl(substr("CLA_UNIFORM_PAYMENT_ADVICE_REP"."INVOICE_NO",3), "CLA_UNIFORM_PAYMENT_ADVICE_REP"."PAYMENT_REFERENCE")
> ```

Comment: It looks like you have syntax errors.  The code you included looks like what I would expect in an Oracle query.  Are you wanting this statement expressed in Crystal Syntax?

Comment: Ok, Yes I a trying to express in Crystal

Comment: can you add screen shot or give the error

Answer (score 0):

There is no direct support for NVL() or SUBSTR() functions, but there are some equivalent functions that will work.  We can extract substrings in Crystal using the MID(str, start, length) function.  The NVL() function would best equate to the ISNULL(field) function.  The MID function will work like a substring function with "str" being the string to search, "start" is the index of where to begin extracting a value, and "length" is the number of character to extract.  The length parameter is optional in the MID function.  When its not used, the function will read the to the end of the string.  The ISNULL function is a bit different from NVL though.  In Crystal, the ISNULL function returns a boolean value that is true when the value of "field" is not null.  To convert the NVL function into an ISNULL function, you will need to wrap it up in an IF/THEN/ELSE statement such as:

```
If ISNULL(field) Then
  ... do something when True
Else
  ... do something when False
```

Its important to remember that datatypes need to match though.  If "field" contains numeric data only, the value returned by the IF/THEN/ELSE statement needs to be numeric as well.

In addition to these functions, you will also need to follow the rules for Crystal Syntax when referencing fields on the report.  In the design of the report you should be able to shortcut having to type this manually by adding the fields to formulas using the Formula Workshop tool.  However, if you want to type them into formulas the syntax is `{TABLE_NAME.COLUMN_NAME}`, no need for parenthesis or double quotes like you use in Oracle.

So with all of this in mind, your formula would be expressed in Crystal Syntax as something like this.

```
IF {CLA_UNIFORM_PAYMENT_ADVICE_REP.SUPPLIER_TYPE} = "SUB" THEN
    {CLA_UNIFORM_PAYMENT_ADVICE_REP.INVOICE_NO}
ELSE
    IF ISNULL(MID({CLA_UNIFORM_PAYMENT_ADVICE_REP.INVOICE_NO},3)) THEN
        {CLA_UNIFORM_PAYMENT_ADVICE_REP.PAYMENT_REFERENCE}
    ELSE
        MID({CLA_UNIFORM_PAYMENT_ADVICE_REP.INVOICE_NO},3)
```

Comment: Thankyou very much = all resolved now